# Scrolling behaviour of nested divs in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scroll

I need to put a wide and long table in a relatively short and narrow container, and I want to keep the table heads always visible. I've got this to work as you can see in the JSFiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/chemLk1z/1/

The important code is this:

```
<div id="h">
    <div id="v">
        <table> [... 10 rows of content ...]
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
#h { 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 100px;     
    overflow-x: scroll; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#v {
    width: -moz-fit-content;
    width: -webkit-fit-content;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

table {
    width: 500px;
    /* Height will be more due to content. */
}
```

As you can see in the JSFiddle, the scrolling experience on Chrome is great. But on Firefox (v38.0.5 Mac OS X) I can't scroll horizontally and vertically at the same time, I need to wait for 10 seconds or so before it allows me to scroll in another dimension.

Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I use Firefox(v37.0 Linux Mint) and I don't see any issue with the working example in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration made vertical-horizontal scroll switching much more comfortable for me:

- Navigate to `about:config` – accept the risk if any warning appears
- Set `mousewheel.transaction.timeout` to **20**.

The value is a delay in milliseconds and the default is a whopping **1500** milliseconds!

For more information, see these [official](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Gecko:Mouse_Wheel_Scrolling#Mouse_wheel_transaction) and [unofficial](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Mousewheel.transaction.timeout) wiki pages.